# Where are all the nice additions to NSManagedObject in RestKit 0.20?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm currently migrating an old RestKit 0.10 project to RestKit 0.20 and I'm really sad to see that all the nice additions to NSManagedObject class like +fetchRequest or +findFirstByAttribute:withValue: have disappeared from NSManagedObject(RKAdditions).

What is the rationale behind this? Have they been replaced by some other library somewhere? Or are we just back to using verbose vanilla Core Data code again?

Comment: I don't use RestKit with Core Data often, but this is what I remember:
Those methods are from the MagicRecords (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord ) framework. RestKit 0.20 dosn't use it anymore.

Maybe it uses Core Data as a caching system, so request can load objects from core data when no internet connection is available?

Comment: http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/ may fill a bit of the gap for you